# access form checkboxes populate sql in vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

So this is slightly more complicated than your typical

```
strSQL = "sql string where & forms!myform.variable & "stuff"
```

I have a table that changes, users add new years to it. So next year will be new 2015 data. I created a form with checkboxes for each year, this form is based on this sql

```
select year from table group by year
```

If a user marks the check boxes for certain years, i want to write a query in vba strsql based on the users checkbox selections. So for example say I currently have 3 years, 2012, 2013, 2014, the user only marks years 2012 and 2014, skipping 2013 would look like

2012 x
2013
2014 x

So in vba strsql I want to write

```
"select * from mytable where year=2012 or year=2014"
```

The problem is the list of years grows, so I can't hard code this it has to be dynamic. For example next year my original sql will select 2015 as well, so the user might mark

2012 x
2013 x
2014
2015 x

So now my vba strsql would be

```
"select * from mytable where year=2012 or year=2013 or year=2015"
```

Every year the list will grow, how can I account for this in vba strsql when the checkbox marks = true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop your values and concatenate to your sql

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim strSQL = "select * from mytable where 1=1"
  Dim cCont As Control
  For Each cCont In Me.Controls
      If TypeName(cCont) = "Checkbox" And cCont.Checked Then
          strSQL = strSQL + " or year=" + cCont.Text
      End If
  Next cCont
```

I added the 1=1 to the where clause so you could just concatinate the `OR` statements without worrying about if its the first `OR` statement or not.

Comment: nice, short, smart :)

Comment: @barker was something wrong with the solution? Why did you unaccept?

Comment: @barker Oh, perhaps I forgot the `and control is checked`?  I've added it here.

Comment: Hey sorry paqogomez, for some reason this only is grabbing the first value in my form. let me type up my code here

Comment: @barker you can post it in the original question if you like, i'm happy to help, though you'd get a wider audience if you posted a new question.

Comment: i just found out this form is based on a table, NOT a query. sorry all my fault. does this change anything? code still only loops first record in form.

Comment: Ok edited the question to more accurately describe the problem :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67344/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-barker).

Comment: as long as his form doesn't have any other checkboxes?

Comment: @Beth, thats a good point, the checkbox name could be tested to make sure that its the right checkbox.  But OP was only concerned about this checkbox and made no mention of others.